# Текст в Opera 11 обрезается

Tags: css

```
div#left_bottom{
float:left;
height:30px;
width:800px;
color: #949494;
background:#141414;
line-height:0.4;
}
```

это происходит из-за строки line-height:0.4; Если её не использовать все отлично, но текст невозможно выровнять по вретикали.

Comment: line-height равно 0.4 чего? Пикселей, процентов или килограммов?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в float:left; height:30px; Из за этого слой не тянется, а ему это ой как нужно в случае если вы начинаете меж строчный интервал дергать.